# Toad how to find all dependencies from package by pressiong F4?

Tags: oracle, toad

I use this script to find all dependencies from my_package:

```
select * from all_dependencies where NAME='PK_PACKAGE'
```

But it returns just this :

```
NAME    TYPE    REFERENCED_OWNER    REFERENCED_NAME REFERENCED_TYPE REFERENCED_LINK_NAME    DEPENDENCY_TYPE
PK_PACKAGE  PACKAGE SYS STANDARD    PACKAGE HARD
```

But when I press F4 on package on TOAD it brings all dependencies. So toad how to find them. In which table?

thanks in advance

Comment: trace your toad session then you will find out what tables it accesses

Comment: check dba_dependencies

Comment: `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` might not work; one should have required privileges to access that view (and not everyone has them).

Comment: @KaushikNayak I do not have dba rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PK_package should most probably be be PK_PACKAGE (all uppercase).

**[EDIT, after some researching]**

If you - in TOAD - go to [Database menu - Spool SQL - Spool SQL to screen] and then click "Deps (uses)" tab in schema browser on that package, you'll get something like this:

```
Session: SCOTT@ORCL
Timestamp: 09:45:50.824
Select a.object_id, a.object_type, a.object_name,
  b.owner ref_owner, b.object_type ref_type, b.object_name ref_name, b.object_id ref_id, b.status ref_status
from   sys.ALL_OBJECTS a,
       sys.ALL_OBJECTS b,
      (Select object_id, referenced_object_id
       from   (select object_id, referenced_object_id
               from   public_dependency
               where  referenced_object_id <> object_id) pd
       start with  object_id = :ObjID
       connect by  prior referenced_object_id =  object_id) c
where a.object_id = c.object_id
and   b.object_id = c.referenced_object_id
and   a.owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
and   b.owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
and   a.object_name <> 'DUAL'
and   b.object_name <> 'DUAL'
:ObjID(INTEGER,IN/OUT)=2357633
```

That would be a query behind a *mouse click* so - have a look at it, maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: I edit my questyion. I alrady use it with all uppercase thanks but it is not working

Comment: @Ersin, what is the result of the following statement: `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'PK_PACKAGE';`

Comment: it brings nothing

Comment: So here's your answer - there's no such package available to you, ALL_OBJECTS and ALL_DEPENDENCIES show data from your own schema as well as other ones, who granted you privileges to access them. Check whether package name is valid. If someone created it using lower or mixed case, that might cause problems. Run this: `select * from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'PK_PACKAGE';`

Comment: sorry :( I missunderstan you. It brings nothing from all_dependicies , all_objects brings data

Comment: it brings this: 

OBJECT_TYPE
PACKAGE
PACKAGE BODY

Comment: Just to make it clear: this `select * from all_DEPENDENCIES where UPPER(object_name) = 'PK_PACKAGE';` returns nothing?

Comment: all_DEPENDENCIES does not have object_name column, it has name column

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry, copy/pasted previous query and modified it, not very successfully, obviously.

Comment: @Ersin, I've edited my message, have a look, please.

Comment: thanks for answer, what is ObjID , how can I write my package name on this code?

Comment: It is column OBJECT_ID from ALL_OBJECTS (identifies your PK_PACKAGE).